# Question about brakes caliper

Tags: brakes

So I was wondering if I can use 2 different brake caliper on my car one is from Duralast and one is from cardone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are both intended for this vehicle they should work ok.  But I'd be cautious when first test driving to make sure they are both performing similarly.  Be alert for any pulling one way or the other.